# Enable numlock when new external keyboard is connected?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, numlock

I'm not sure this is possible, but I thought why not to ask.

I have a laptop without a numeric block, and use it sometimes with external keyboard. <kbd>Numlock</kbd> for the internal keyboard = useless, so I never use it.

No <kbd>numlock</kbd> for the external keyboard = I press arrows etc instead of numbers by accident.

So, is there any possibility to enable <kbd>numlock</kbd> when the laptop starts with the external keyboard, and no <kbd>numlock</kbd> with only the internal?

I guess maybe some trickery with `lsusb` and `numlockx`?

Comment: Looking for exactly the same thing here. [This script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764567/96588) may be useful; I haven't had the opportunity to test and simplify it yet.

Comment: @l0b0 I've made that script - will now put it on AUR. Here -> https://github.com/MightyPork/autonumlock

Comment: Under which unix variant? Only under X11 (i.e. in the GUI) or also on the console?

Comment: Think it's solved, my script works fine.. only under X, i don't go to console often (mostly only to kill X when it freezes)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've made a script for that:

- https://github.com/MightyPork/autonumlock

It's now also available in AUR as `autonumlock-git`. Basically loop with `lsusb`, `grep` and checking if the device ID is there or not.

Output - numlockx on / off.