# Fix Numlock for one specific keyboard only (leaving the behaviour of other devices untouched)

Tags: keyboard-event, numlock

My question is basically identical to this U&L Q&A titled:  [Enable numlock only for external keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168815/enable-numlock-only-for-external-keyboard), with a slight difference.

I have the solution running to enable <kbd>Numlock</kbd> whenever an external keyboard is plugged into my laptop etc., but I still occasionally type on the laptops keyboard, even with the external keyboard is plugged in.

How can I permanently set <kbd>Numlock</kbd> on the external keyboard while leaving the behaviour for other devices like the internal keyboard unchanged?

I'm not afraid of getting into driver programming eventually, if that's what it takes. Just make sure to point me somewhere where I can learn what to do next.

Comment: Outside of trapping every keypress, for eg.https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89538/how-to-tell-which-keyboard-was-used-to-press-a-key, and acting accordingly if it came form USB vs. nonUSB, I wasn't able to find a method that would do what you want.

Comment: Might be useful, shows udev rules for when keyboard is plugged/unplgged in - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161455.